# How to reduce the convex shape of a surface, to make it more planar?

Tags: modifiers

How to reduce the curved shape of a surface, to make it more planar ?. Doesn't have to be perfectly flat like a plane or grid. I want to 'relax' the shape so become less convex.

[image: curved surface]

Answer (score 2):

There is this neat trick that works in almost every 3d software out there that forces vertices to go to same plane.
Simply go to edit mode by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> select all by pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, press <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> depending which plane you want them to be thrown at, and then press <kbd>0</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick supplement to the answers already given ..  for scaling, you have the option of creating your own orientation..

- Select all the faces, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to find an axis on the mean surface normal
- With a suitable pivot point, (maybe *Median*) <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to scale down that axis
- You can use Proportional Editing (<kbd>O</kbd>) to vary the effect.

Answer (score 0):

there are some tools that might help you.
ctrl v - smooth vertex

file - user preferences - addons - mesh - activate looptools.
you will find a few helpfull new entries at the right side in the tools menu